# Record screen in mpeg format

Tags: video-streaming, directshow, screen-capture

By using a PushSourseDesktop(windows SDK samples) Filter we only can write in AVI format with AVI MUX.I  added MS Screen Encoder to decrease size of recorded videos.I would like to save result in a file ,what can complete the graph?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. `PushSourceDesktop` streams you desktop picture into DriectShow pipeline, there is no direct relation to storage format here
2. The logic may be either "I would like to have it in MPEG (MPEG-2? MPEG-4?) format what filters do I use?", or "I would like to have it with screen codec, what format can it eventually be?" but not the way it is asked in the Q above.
3. Microsoft ships Windows with [Windows Media Video 9 Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) codec (`MSS2' FourCC) which is good for this type of video, and ASF/WMV file format.

Answer (score 0):

To write an AVI file insert AVI Mux filter between the encoder and File Writer.